# C# LINQ join With Just One Row

Tags: c#, linq, join

I'm trying to make a query that grabs a single row from an SQL database and updates it.

```
TableA
AId
AValue

TableB
BId
AId
BValue
```

Ok, so TableA and TableB are linked by AId.  I want to select a row in TableB based on AValue using a join.  The following query is what I have and only grabs a value from TableB based on AId, I just don't know how to grab a row from TableB using AValue.  I know you would need to use a join, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

```
var row = DbObject.TableB.Single(x => x.AId == 1)
row.BValue = 1;
DbObject.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a LINQ query to do what you are asking.

```
var row = (from b in TableB
        join a in TableA on a.AId equals b.AId
        where a.AValue = yourValue).Single();
```

Comment: Ok, from there, do I have to grab the result using a foreach loop?
There is only going to be one value grabbed in the query.  Is there a more efficient way to get the result because there is only one expected value?

Comment: I edited my answer to use Single() so you don't have to use a foreach loop.

Comment: a.AId equals b.AId
^ a quick correction, otherwise, it seems to be working so heyo! :D
thanks